# moving data segment address DS via direct addressing mode

Tags: assembly

In X86 assembly language, in order to move the start address of the data segment to the data segment register, one has to first move it to `AX` and then move `AX` to `DS`. Like this:

```
DTSEG     SEGMENT
 ...
DTSEG     ENDS
CDSEG     SEGMENT
MAIN      PROC   FAR
          MOV    AX,DTSEG
          MOV    DS,AX
CDSEG     ENDS
          END    MAIN
```

I want to know, are we using direct addressing mode in the first line? Now consider, we define a string byte in the data segment like this

```
DTSEG     SEGMENT
DATA      DB        'HELLO'
DTSEG     ENDS
```

This time, we have to load the effective address using `MOV   AX,OFFSET DATA` or `LEA   AX,DATA`. Both of them are valid. Now, the second question is do we still use direct addressing mode?

Then, the third question is why don't we load the effective address of the data segment? Like this:

```
MOV    AX,OFFSET DTSEG    ; ???
LEA    AX,DTSEG           ; ???
```

Is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following lines don't use an addressing mode. Addressing modes are only used with memory operands and these instructions move an immediate operand into a register operand:

```
MOV AX,DTSEG
MOV AX,OFFSET DATA
```

Only the following instruction has memory operand, and yes it uses direct addressing:

```
LEA AX,DATA
```

Normally a memory operand indicates a location in memory that the instruction reads from and/or writes to, but the LEA instruction is different. Instead the offset (address) of the location of the memory operand is loaded into a register.

The following instructions doesn't do what you expect to do:

```
MOV AX,OFFSET DTSEG
```

It loads AX with the offset of the beginning of the DTSEG segment, which is 0.

The following instruction is invalid:

```
LEA AX, DTSEG
```

You can't use a segment as a memory operand.

Most of your misunderstanding comes from how segmented addressing works in 16-bit real mode code. Every memory operand references a location in memory through a segment and offset pair. Both the segment and offset are 16-bit values, and they're combined to form a 20-bit address by multiplying the segment part by 16 and adding it to the offset.  When accessing data the segment part always comes from a segment register, usually implicitly the DS register. The offset part is usually explicitly given as a memory operand.

So for example:

```
CDSEG SEGMENT
     mov  ax, DTSEG
     mov  ds, ax
     mov  bx, OFFSET DATA
     mov  ax, [bx]
     mov  dx, cs:[bx]
CDSEG ENDS
```

The instruction `mov ax, [bx]` loads 16-bit value stored at offset DATA in the segment DTSEG. The instruction `mov ax, cs:[bx]` loads the 16-bit value stored at offset DATA of the segment CDSEG.  The first example loads the value stored in DATA, the second example loads whatever happens to be stored at the same offset in the code segment.

Comment: Why do you say "these instructions move an immediate operand...". Although OFFSET DATA is an integer, but it points to a memory location. It is not an immediate value such as MOV AX,2

Comment: @mahmood Immediate operands are operands that are encoded as part of the instruction. Whether they're supposed to represent addresses or not doesn't make a difference to the CPU. It just uses the value encoded into the instruction as the operand.

Comment: See http://goo.gl/eZGILc where the figures are taken from 8086 programming and interface book by W. Treibel. Also, look at http://goo.gl/VRNlDR where in the first and second page, it shows some examples about the modes.

Comment: As you can see, in `MOV AX,OFFSET DATA`, if the location of DATA is 10h, then we are moving the content of the tenth location to AX which means `MOV AX,[10h]`.  So I disagree with you that OFFSET means immediate mode. In my opinion, OFFSET is EFFECTIVE ADDRESS. Isn't that?

Comment: @mahmood No, your links don't support your assertion. If DATA is located at offset 10h in DTSEG then `MOV AX, OFFSET DATA` will load AX with the value 10h, which is an immediate operand. If you want load the value stored at DATA then, assuming DS has already been loaded with DTSEG, you would write `MOV AX, DATA` or `MOV AX, [DATA]`. Both are equivalent to MASM and both use a memory operand with direct addressing.

Comment: But with emu8086,I use `MOV AX,OFFSET DATA` and `LEA AX,DATA` interchangeably!!! and codes work similar. This is confusing...

Comment: @mahmood They end up doing the same thing. That's because LEA uses its memory operand in an usual way. Instead of loading the value stored in the memory operand, it loads the offset of the memory operand. With `MOV, AX, OFFSET DATA`, the value of DATA is encoded as an immediate operand. With `MOV AX, DATA` and `LEA AX, DATA` the value of DATA is encoded as a displacement in a memory operand. It might help to think of `MOV AX, [DATA + BX]` and `LEA AX, [DATA + BX]`. Both encode DATA as a displacement, but only the former reads from memory. The later loads AX with the offset of DATA plus BX.

Comment: Will only make the observation that when you do `MOV AX,DTSEG` it is an immediate value that gets fixed up by the DOS EXE loader so that the executable can be relocated. Part of the value is filled in by the linker when the EXE is generated, and then fixed up at run-time